# Join two tables to a model with lambda

Tags: c#, join, lambda

I'm joining 2 tables in my code. And the code seems to work. But when I try a `Debug.WriteLine()` it is empty.

I have seen solutions. But not with a model.

```
IQueryable<Order_OrderCart_OrderLogisticsModel> model = repository.Orders
    .Join(
    repository.OrderLogisticss,
    o => o.ID,
    ol => ol.OrderID,
    (o, ol) => new { Order = o, OrderLogistics = ol })
    .Where(x => x.OrderLogistics.DepartureDate == 40826)
    .Join(
    repository.OrderCarts,
    o => o.Order.ID,
    oc => oc.OrderID,
    (o, oc) => new Order_OrderCart_OrderLogisticsModel { Order = o.Order, Logistics = o.OrderLogistics, Cart = oc })
    .Where(x => x.Cart.Sealed != false);

foreach (var item in model)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Cart.Sealed);
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Order.ID);
    Debug.WriteLine(item.Logistics.DepartureDate);

}
```

**Question:**
So my question is what am I doing wrong? I have other code that only has one join and that does work. Only this does not work.

Please do only answer with lambda code. Yes I know original linq is a bit faster but I like to learn lambda.

**Update:**

The generated SQL that seems to work fine.

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Extent1].[StatusID] AS [StatusID], 
    [Extent1].[KlantID] AS [KlantID], 
    [Extent1].[SoortID] AS [SoortID], 
    [Extent1].[isVerwijderd] AS [isVerwijderd], 
    [Extent1].[Aantalkarren] AS [Aantalkarren], 
    [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
    [Extent2].[OpdrachtID] AS [OpdrachtID], 
    [Extent2].[Vertrekdatum] AS [Vertrekdatum], 
    [Extent2].[Vertrektijd] AS [Vertrektijd], 
    [Extent3].[ID] AS [ID2], 
    [Extent3].[OpdrachtID] AS [OpdrachtID1], 
    [Extent3].[KarID] AS [KarID], 
    [Extent3].[Gesealed] AS [Gesealed], 
    [Extent3].[Aantal] AS [Aantal], 
    [Extent3].[SamenvoegOpdrachtkarID] AS [SamenvoegOpdrachtkarID], 
    [Extent3].[AanmaakDatum] AS [AanmaakDatum]
    FROM   [dbo].[Opdracht] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OpdrachtLogistiek] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[OpdrachtID]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[OpdrachtKar] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent3].[OpdrachtID]
    WHERE (40826 = [Extent2].[Vertrekdatum]) AND ( NOT ((0 = [Extent3].[Gesealed]) AND ([Extent3].[Gesealed] IS NOT NULL)))
```

**Update 2:**

The code is okay. The data I wanted to display did not exist. I made a well known typing mistake. I filled in "40826" instead of "40822". Thanks for all the help.

**Update 3:** 
For people wondering how my model looks like:

```
public class Order_OrderCart_OrderLogisticsModel
{
    private Order order;

    public Order Order
    {
        get { return order; }
        set { order = value; }
    }

    private OrderLogistics logistics;

    public OrderLogistics Logistics
    {
        get { return logistics; }
        set { logistics = value; }
    }

    private OrderCart cart;

    public OrderCart Cart
    {
        get { return cart; }
        set { cart = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: by just reading your code, i cant see what is wrong, asuming you are executing this against a database, try looking at the query that executes against the databse to give you a hint on what is wrong. You can have the query always handy in your output window by adding this code to your dbcontext class 

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.Log = (query)=> Debug.Write(query);
}

Comment: @GerriePretorius you can use [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to see to SQL generated

Comment: Thanks for the options. I liked Gerrie's suggestion better because it's simple.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code testable I would prefer splitting conditions from joining. In the end wheres' conditions will be evaluated at right time, but during debugging you will be able to view if there are results of sub-queries.

```
var suitableOrderLogistics = repository.OrderLogisticss.Where(ol => 
    ol.DepartureDate == 40826);
var suitableOrderCarts = repository.OrderCarts.Where(oc => oc.Sealed != false);

var model = repository.Orders
.Join(
  suitableOrderLogistics,
  o => o.ID,
  ol => ol.OrderID,
  (o, ol) => new { OrderId = o.Id, Order = o, OrderLogistics = ol })
.Join(
  suitableOrderCarts ,
  o => o.OrderId,
  oc => oc.OrderID,
  (o, oc) => new Order_OrderCart_OrderLogisticsModel { Order = o.Order, Logistics = o.OrderLogistics, Cart = oc });
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.
The suitables are correctly filled as expected.

But still the writelines stay emtpy. But if I delete the where statements from my original code then the writelines work as expected.

So because of my where statements the writelines are unable to show data.

Comment: oc.Sealed != false == oc.Sealed